# A very basic cipher

Tags: mathematics, cipher

The following is a relatively basic cipher I have constructed. I still hope it's entertaining.

---

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _
A _ A A A
A A _
A A
A D
B
B _
A A
B H
```

---

The answer is the **9-letter name** of a famous man who helped created this puzzle.

###### Small hint:

> Note the [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag.

##### Medium hint:

> Look at the name of puzzle, and remember that this involves math.

Comment: I can change it then. I'm quite new to this exchange. Are the horizontal spaces useful?

Comment: You mean the spaces between the underscores? I believe they are since the rest of the puzzle includes spaces between the letters. Also, if you ever want feedback before posting a puzzle, you can always join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair), or post your puzzle in [the sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox).

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial thoughts:

> Nine lines in the cipher, and nine letters to find, so likely one letter per line, so we are looking for a way to turn a row of multiple symbols into a single letter.
>
> The [mathematics](/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag combined with the low number of distinct symbols, and the latest letter being 'H' means we could be looking at a simple A=1, B=2 etc translation, with '_' representing 0.

Which gives us:

> 0000000
> 10111
> 110
> 11
> 14
> 2
> 20
> 11
> 28

But that doesn't obviously translate back to letters.

More thoughts:

> The rapidly reducing line lengths, and nothing above N-1 in row N makes it look like we could have numbers in different bases. So try interpreting row N in base N.

Which gives us:

> ```
>  0000000 (1) =  7 = G
>    10111 (2) = 23 = W
>      110 (3) = 12 = L
>       11 (4) =  5 = E
>       14 (5) =  9 = I
>        2 (6) =  2 = B
>       20 (7) = 14 = N
>       11 (8) =  9 = I
>       28 (9) = 26 = Z
> ```

So the famous man we are looking for is:

> Gottfried Wilhelm von Leibniz

As for the hints:

> Now that I've solved it, I realise in that the second hint pointing to this  "basic" cipher, and was providing a big signpost to the different bases, which I completely failed to spot...

Comment: Congratulations on solving the cipher! : ) Leibniz is considered to be the inventor of the binary system as well as the first to show its use in a computing machine.